# prevent Yahoo messenger from converting emoticons to graphical smilies

Tags: yahoo-messenger, emoticons

Yahoo Messenger seems to automatically convert certain sequences of characters into graphical smilies. I think that this is annoying because I frequently try to send and receive lines of code, which get mangled. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to disable the emoticons (smileys) you can do so in the **Preferences**, go to **Messages** and under **Miscellaneous** clear the box that enables emoticons.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I don't know how I missed that after looking so much for this option.

Comment: truth to be told, i wouldn't have the faintest about Y!M or other messenger clients, i do not use this stuff, praise the mighty powers of a well known internet search engine. :)